# Can the value obtained from GridSearchCV be used to find the best model after hyperparameter tuning? - sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I have two model: k-nearest neighbours and a ridge classifier. In order to find the best hyperparameters, the code below is run.

For ridge classifier

```
# example of grid searching key hyperparametres for ridge classifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
# define models and parameters
model = RidgeClassifier()
alpha = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
# define grid search
grid = dict(alpha=alpha)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, grid , n_jobs=1, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy',error_score=0)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, Y)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

```
output
Best: 0.750456 using {'alpha': 0.1}
```

For K-Nearest Neighbors

```
# finding best parameter of K-Nearest Neighbors
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
# define dataset
# define models and parameters
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
n_neighbors = range(1, 21, 2)
weights = ['uniform', 'distance']
metric = ['euclidean', 'manhattan', 'minkowski']
# define grid search
grid = dict(n_neighbors=n_neighbors,weights=weights,metric=metric)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, grid, n_jobs=1, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy',error_score=0)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, Y)
# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

```
output
Best: 0.999693 using {'metric': 'manhattan', 'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'}
```

Does that mean ridge classifier is better than K-Nearest Neighbors( I am assuming cross-validtion is already done after doing GridSearch, hence the name "GridSearchCV"),as it has a higher accuray? Or do I need now use the best hyperparameter which was found to do cross-validtion (say k-fold) to find the most accurate model out of them two?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (Are your results switched?  The printed hyperparameters are for the wrong classifiers.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, its been fixed :)